# Bootstrap clock picker Auto Adjustment Issue in modal popup

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal, clockpicker

I am using bootstrap clockpicker(http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/). I am not able to auto adjust clockpicker position.

Here is the code for clockpicker:

```
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
        placement: 'bottom',
        align: 'left',
        autoclose: true,
        donetext: 'Done',
        //twelvehour: true,
});
```

My client like this plugin very much and he want me to use this in his application. But i didn't found any solution to auto adjust clockpicker. Anyone have idea? I'll be very thankfull...

Comment: can you give html code also?

Comment: @PareshMaghodiya Here is my HTML Code `<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control clockpicker before" data-type="before" id="from_time" name="" value="10:00">
        <span class="input-group-addon clock_icon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
 </div>`

Comment: You give `clockpicker` class in `div` not in `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker"> 
    <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control" id="from_time" name="from_time" value="10:00"> 
    <span class="input-group-addon clock_icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
    placement: 'bottom',
    align: 'left',
    autoclose: true,
    donetext: 'Done',
});
</script>
```

Comment: By doing this clockpicker shows on top of element but in bottom also. Can you please create a fiddle for me

Comment: I try to create fiddle but block external jquery blocked so its not work https://jsfiddle.net/cwdaq8b3/1/

Comment: You can remove `data-type="before"` from html code. check new edited code above

Comment: Can't remove `data-type="before"` because i m using that attribute. That attribute is not linked with clockpicker